# Disk intermittently goes to 100% actviity - system pauses

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, cpu-usage

Windows 8.1 system.

Sometimes the disk suddenly go 100% highest active time for 1 or 2 seconds, and at the same time CPU usage goes down.

During these period, screen processing does not work any more. Processing returns to normal when high disk activity goes down.

How can I fix it?

Comment: dish?dish or disk kindly brief your problem

Comment: Start with a disk check (e.g.: `chkdsk c:`), check the drive's SMART status as well.

Comment: run this command: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60. Now wait for the issue. After Windows is back from the freeze, go back to the cmd.exe, press a key to stop logging and share the trace. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: i do not understand what magicandre1981 says

Comment: what don't you understand? Install the SDK/WPT, reboot, run cmd.exe as admin (do a rightclick and select "Run as admin"), copy/paste the xperf command in to the cmd Window and press ENTER. Now wait for the 100% activity. If Windows is back normal, go to the cmd and press a key to stop the logging. Compress the ETL to reduce the size, upload it to OneDrive and post a link here.

Comment: i have find out my problems solution. which is caused by hard disks AAM mode.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a faster disk. 
This is caused by the CPU being forced to wait for the hard disk to send the data.